# Button image error when clicked

Tags: html, css

I have an input element set as a submit button which displays fine

[image]

However when the button is clicked this happens

[image]

> Html code:

`<input class="css-button-submit" type="submit" value="">`

> CSS:

```
`.css-button-submit
{
        width:43px;
        height:20px;
        border:none;
        position:relative;
        left:10px;
        background:url("/Images/icon-search.png") no-repeat;
}`
```

Is there a way to correct this so that the image stays static?

Comment: We need more details, please.

Comment: Identical button can be created without using images (all modern browsers support rounded corners). How about switching to just css-styled button?

Comment: Is it possible for you to create a codePen so we can check out what's going on?

Comment: I can create a normal button without any problems, and adapt the image in, however I also have a reset button which is styled completely through css and just wanted the submit button to be the same. How do I create a codePen?

Comment: I tried to create a codePen through JSFiddle but it won't accept my css